# VBA For loop on columns

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Hello guys I'm trying to loop over those values on the columns (2 values per row on image above).

What I want is to pass to a for loop Value is "A=1, B=1"," A=1,B=2" and so on.

I tried with the following code, but it is not working.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim celula As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("PARAM").Range("A2:A9")
Set runge = Worksheets("PARAM").Range("B2:B9")

For Each cell In rng
For Each celula In runge

e.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.examples/test" & **cell** & "/" & **celula**

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

DoEvents

Loop
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that code didn't work...  You've missed the `i` from `ie` in `ie.Visible`, you never created the `ie` as an object, nor `Set` it to the created object, the URL you are trying to navigate to is invalid, you are missing the `Next` statements from  your `For Each` loops...  If this is the code you are actually trying to run (as opposed to you just copying bits and pieces into the Question) then you need to sort all of the above.  If however you have only copied bits over, please edit the question, show the full code, and describe a little more clearly what's not working

Comment: Reading this might help improve your Stack Overflow experience: [mcve] (and [ask], too). "it's not working" isn't a *specific problem* this community can help you solve.

Comment: @Dave obviously i have the next statement on my code . The point was to pass the values on the columns to the for loop so i didnt write all the code. I think user h2so4 answer is correct, i will try it later. Many thanks

Comment: *And yes on my code i have the "i", but i copied it wrong @Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible correction

```
Dim i%

For i = 2 To 9 ' will send 9 requests based on the value of column A and column B

e.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.examples/test" & Cells(i, 1) & "/" & Cells(i, 2)

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

DoEvents

Loop
Next i
```